# ERROR: gcloud crashed (ModuleNotFoundError): No module named 'distutils.spawn'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gcloud

When I am going to deploy app.yaml in GCP, suddenly getting error i.e. "ERROR: gcloud crashed (ModuleNotFoundError): No module named 'distutils.spawn'". Please suggest me the solution. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 with PHP App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing this and then deploy:

sudo apt install python3-distutils -y or python3 -m pip install setuptools

Comment: Tried, but not solved for php environment. For python environment it's perfectly deployed. I need php environment.

Comment: Issue resolved by updating linux package, removing and reinstalling google-cloud-sdk.

Comment: Great, was going to suggest the same.

Comment: Yes sure friend.